# Passing Two models in one view causing controller issues ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

So I make a view model that contains both of them like so:

```
public class TwoPageViewModel
    {

        public IEnumerable<Leepio.Models.Project> Model1 { get; set; }
        public IndexViewModel Model2 { get; set; }

     }
```

In the Views/Manage/Index.cshtml I have this:

```
  @using Leepio.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model Leepio.Models.TwoPageViewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

<p class="text-success">@ViewBag.StatusMessage</p>
<div>
    <h4>Change your account settings</h4>
    <hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">



<dt>Phone Number:</dt>
<dd>
    @(Model.Model2.PhoneNumber ?? "None")
    [
    @if (Model.Model2.PhoneNumber != null)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Change", "AddPhoneNumber")


    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddPhoneNumber")
    }
    ]
</dd>
<dt>Email</dt>
<dd>

    @(Model.Model2.Email ?? "None")
    [
    @if (Model.Model2.Email != null)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeEmail")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeEmail")
    }
    ]


</dd>


@if (Model.Model2.FirstName != null)
{
    <dt>First Name</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.FirstName ?? "None")
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.FirstName != null)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeFirstName")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeFirstName")
        }
        ]


    </dd>
}
@if (Model.Model2.LastName != null)
{
    <dt>Last Name</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.LastName ?? "None")
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.LastName != null)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeLastName")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeLastName")
        }
        ]


    </dd>
}
<dt>City</dt>
<dd>

    @(Model.Model2.City ?? "None")
    [
    @if (Model.Model2.City != null)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeCity")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeCity")
    }
    ]


</dd>
@if (Model.Model2.CompanyName != null)
{
    <dt>CompanyName</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.CompanyName ?? "None")
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.CompanyName != null)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeUserName")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeUserName")
        }
        ]


    </dd>
}
<dt>ZipCode</dt>
<dd>

    @(Model.Model2.ZipCode ?? "None")
    [
    @if (Model.Model2.ZipCode != null)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeZipCode")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeZipCode")
    }
    ]


</dd>
@if (Model.Model2.Region != null)
{
    <dt>Region</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.Region ?? "None")
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.Region != null)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeRegion")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeRegion")
        }
        ]


    </dd>
}

@if (Model.Model2.NrEmployees != 0)
{
    <dt>NrEmployees</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.NrEmployees)
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.NrEmployees != 0)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeNrEmployees")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeNrEmployees")
        }
        ]


    </dd>
}

@if (Model.Model2.WorkField != null)
{
    <dt>WorkField</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.WorkField ?? "None")
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.WorkField != null)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeWorkField")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeWorkField")
        }
        ]

    </dd>
}
<dt>Language</dt>
<dd>

    @(Model.Model2.Language ?? "None")
    [
    @if (Model.Model2.Language != null)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeLanguage")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeLanguage")
    }
    ]

</dd>


@if (Model.Model2.University != null)
{
    <dt>University</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.University ?? "None")
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.University != null)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeUniversity")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeUniversity")
        }
        ]

    </dd>
}


@if (Model.Model2.StudyProgramme != null)
{
    <dt>StudyProgramme</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.StudyProgramme ?? "None")
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.StudyProgramme != null)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeStudyProgramme")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeStudyProgramme")
        }
        ]

    </dd>
}


@if (Model.Model2.Semester != 0)
{
    <dt>Semester</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.Semester)
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.Semester != 0)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeSemester")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeSemester")
        }
        ]

    </dd>
}

@if (Model.Model2.GraduationDate != null)
{
    <dt>GraduationDate</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.GraduationDate ?? "None")
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.GraduationDate != null)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeGraduationDate")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeGraduationDate")
        }
        ]

    </dd>
}
<dt>Description</dt>
<dd>

    @(Model.Model2.Description ?? "None")
    [
    @if (Model.Model2.Description != null)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeDescription")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeDescription")
    }
    ]

</dd>

@if (Model.Model2.Skills != null)
{
    <dt>Skills</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.Skills ?? "None")
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.Skills != null)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeSkills")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeSkills")
        }
        ]

    </dd>
}
@if (@Model.Model2.Experience != null)
{
    <dt>Experience</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.Experience ?? "None")
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.Experience != null)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeExperience")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeExperience")
        }
        ]

    </dd>
}

@if (Model.Model2.Website != null)
{
    <dt>Website</dt>
    <dd>

        @(Model.Model2.Website ?? "None")
        [
        @if (Model.Model2.Website != null)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change", "ChangeWebsite")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ChangeWebsite")
        }
        ]

    </dd>
}



<dt>Password:</dt>
<dd>
    [
    @if (Model.Model2.HasPassword)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Change your password", "ChangePassword")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Create", "SetPassword")
    }
    ]
</dd>

</dl>


    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Title", "Index", new { SortOrder = (ViewBag.SortOrder == null ? "Asc" : (ViewBag.SortOrder == "Asc" ? "Desc" : "Asc")), SortBy = "Title" })

            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application Deadline", "Index", new { SortOrder = (ViewBag.SortOrder == null ? "Asc" : (ViewBag.SortOrder == "Asc" ? "Desc" : "Asc")), SortBy = "ApplicationDeadline" }) <br />
                @Html.ActionLink("Hourly Rate (DKK)", "Index", new { SortOrder = (ViewBag.SortOrder == null ? "Asc" : (ViewBag.SortOrder == "Asc" ? "Desc" : "Asc")), SortBy = "HourlyRate" })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Skill requirements", "Index", new { SortOrder = (ViewBag.SortOrder == null ? "Asc" : (ViewBag.SortOrder == "Asc" ? "Desc" : "Asc")), SortBy = "RequiredSkills" })
            </th>


        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Model1)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApplicationDeadline)<br />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HourlyRate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequiredSkills)
                </td>


                <td>

                    @if (item.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId())

                    {

                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Projects", new { id = item.ProjectId }, null)

                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Projects", new { id = item.ProjectId }, null)
                    }

                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Projects", new { id = item.ProjectId }, null) |
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>



</div>
```

Here the Edit, Delete and Details actions are not found. They are inside the Controllers\ProjectsController.cs

How can I reference the file to know to take the actions from this controller? There is something I'm missing

Comment: Try this  `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Projects", new { id = item.ProjectId })`, look at [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: It still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide controller name and pass required params. use this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Projects", new { id = item.ProjectId }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Projects", new { id = item.ProjectId }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Projects", new { id = item.ProjectId }, null)
```

Comment: so, in your view if you use Model.Model2, you are getting error? can you post that code

Comment: why is @ added here(@Model.)? @if (@Model.Model2.Experience != null).Formating mistake? If not, in which line are you getting the issue. Need more info

Comment: keep a debugger at the starting of the page and check it

Comment: meant debug your application, put a breakpoint in this line - @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage";
} and check what is happening

Comment: @crystyxn, This answer is correct and should be accepted. Your other error has got nothing to do with the code you have shown, but its self explanatory - somewhere you calling a view that has `@model TwoPageViewModel` but you passing it an instance of `IndexViewModel`